# WPF - Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type 'System.Uri'

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a simple user control to display a hyperlink in a textblock:

LinkTextBlock.xaml:

```
<TextBlock >
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Url, ElementName=root}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=root}" />
    </Hyperlink>   
</TextBlock>
```

LinkTextBlock.xaml.cs:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Url", typeof (string), typeof (LinkTextBlock));
public string Url
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(UrlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string), typeof (LinkTextBlock));
public string Text
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```

Then, in a DataTemplate for a ListBox I have:

```
<Controls:LinkTextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" Url="{Binding Email}" />
```

When I run the application, it seems to work perfectly. The control shows the hyperlinks correctly and there are no apparent problems. However, when I look at the Output window I get exceptions, one for each ListBox item:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 22 : Cannot
>   convert '' from type '' to
>   type 'System.Uri' for 'en-US' culture
>   with default conversions; consider
>   using Converter property of Binding.
>   NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException:
>   UriTypeConverter cannot convert from
>   (null).    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object
>   value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object
>   value)    at
>   System.UriTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object
>   value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object
>   o, Type destinationType,
>   DependencyObject targetElement,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean
>   isForward)'

Why is this happening? I know the binding error is a result of the binding to NavigateURI.
Do you have any suggestions for me? What can I do about it? I really appreciate your inputs.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of object is "Email" coming from. What is its type?

Comment: Peter, Email is just a string property of the object bound to the current DataContext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is when performing an implicit conversion from string to Uri, since NavigateUri is of type Uri.
I needed to create a converter to convert string to Uri, change my property from String to Uri, and it all worked fine without exceptions.

Comment: can you provide the converter

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't this

```
<TextBlock >
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Url, ElementName=root}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=root}" />
    </Hyperlink>   
</TextBlock>
```

be this?

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=root}">
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Url, ElementName=root}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Not really. Hyperlink doesn't have a visual representation. So if you do what you're suggesting, you're going to end up with just a TextBlock without anything to click on.

Comment: And, on top of not working visually, your suggestion does not address my issue, which is the exceptions. Thanks.